# coloring a table row in python using HTML.py module

Tags: python

```
htmlcode=HTML.table(table_data,header_row=['Check','Setup','status','Logs','Comment'],
            col_width=['30%','20%','20%','10%','30%'])
```

here i want to color the table header row with grey color. as a beginner in this language i couldnt figure it out. here im using a HTML.py module

i got this module from http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html
so pls help in coloring the header row.

Comment: @Avinash can u give any solution?

Comment: right now, i'm on my mobile ..will try it when I get to home, mean while you have a look at the source code of `HTML` module ..may be it can give you a basic idea to solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may specify a background color for the header row, by using a TableRow object instead of a list. 
For example:

`t =  HTML.Table(header_row = HTML.TableRow(['x', 'square(x)', 'cube(x)'], bgcolor='yellow'))`

---

Source : one of the comments on module page : http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can change them via anything simple (only allows for per-cell additions w/ color change). I would suggest linking in a css file with some .th{background-color:orange;} stylings, or use another module that is more robust.

Comment: how to link css file and can you give any example code how to use it. @jeff

Comment: It's outputting html code, which I'm assuming you're dropping in some other html file, link the css in the html.  Try w3school.com for examples and howto's on it.  If you're looking for a full on web framework try zope or django

Comment: And as a note, if it doesn't look like you put in much effort figuring out something, most community members at most places won't spend much time helping.

Comment: @jeff as he was a novice, it takes some time and effort to get used to this stuff, let us encourage our new community member by providing sufficient amount of help as required :)

Comment: @Avinash yeah, I completely understand this, I'm trying to get across the idea that a little leg work doesn't hurt.  I just sometimes come across a little harsher than I should. The framework being used looks very fledgeling, and for a newbie I would honestly suggest something with stronger documentation.